# How to use local .html file in Template in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I was thinking I could just make another .html file and refer to it using the template or templateUrl but that doesn't seem to work. There has to be a better way than throwing a bunch of html into the middle of my code. If I use template: 'myHTML.html' it just prints out the literal and using templateUrl it throws an error. Does someone know how to just use a local .html file and have it load into the template?

Here is a view of my ugly code:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  template: '<div class="modal-header">\
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Reserved Vehicle: </h2>\
                </div>\
                <div class="modal-body">\
                    <ul class="carInfo">\
                        <li class="listFormat"><div class="divSet">Make:</div><div class="listInfoAlign">{{car.make}}</div></li>\
                            <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <li class="listFormat"><div class="divSet">Model:</div><div class="listInfoAlign">{{car.model}}</div></li>\
                            <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <li class="listFormat"><div class="divSet">Year:</div><div class="listInfoAlign">{{car.year}}</div></li>\
                            <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <li class="listFormat"><div class="divSet">Color:</div><div class="listInfoAlign">{{car.color}}</div></li>\
                            <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <li class="listFormat"><div class="divSet">Mileage:</div><div class="listInfoAlign">{{car.mileage | number}}</div></li>\
                            <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <li class="listFormat"><div class="divSet">Doors:</div><div class="listInfoAlign">{{car.doors}}</div></li>\
                            <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <li class="listFormat"><div class="divSet">Horsepower:</div><div class="listInfoAlign">{{car.horsepower}}</div></li>\
                            <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <li class="listFormat"><div class="divSet">Price:</div><p class="listInfoAlign">{{car.price | number}}</p></li>\
                            <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                    </ul>\
                <div class="formContainer">\
                    <form name="form" class="formStyles" ng-submit="submit()">\
                        <p class="para">\
                            <label class="labelCell" id="nameLabel" for="name">Name:</label>\
                            <input class="inputStyles" type="text" id="name" name="name" required>\
                        </p>\
                    <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <p class="para">\
                            <label class="labelCell" id="phoneLabel" for="phone">Phone:</label>\
                            <input class="inputStyles" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required/>\
                        </p>\
                    <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <p class="para">\
                            <label class="labelCell" id="emailLabel" for="name">Email:</label>\
                            <input class="inputStyles" type="email" id="email" name="email" required/>\
                        </p>\
                    <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <p class="para">\
                            <label class="labelCell" id="addressLabel" for="address">Address:</label>\
                            <input class="inputStyles" type="text" id="address" name="address"/>\
                        </p>\
                    <div class="clearDiv"></div>\
                        <p class="para textAreaPara">\
                            <label id="commentsLabel" for="comments">Notes:</label>\
                        <br>\
                        <textarea class="textInputStyles" placeholder="Please include any additional notes you might have here." rows="5" cols="50" id="comments"name="comments" maxlength="500"></textarea>\
                        </p>\
      <div>\
        <div class="submitButton">\
            <input id="submitID" type="submit" value="Submit"/>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
                    </form>\
                </div>\
            </div>',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
      car: function(){

      return $scope.car[index];
      }
  }
});
```

I hope this is not how it has to be done and I'm sure it isn't, but I've looked for an answer and think maybe I just don't know how articulate my question. I would like all of that html code to be in its own file and then used the template or templateUrl to get the information. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great example: http://plnkr.co/edit/lHTw0p381rcnnUKiJTpB?p=preview

Straight from the docs: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (just search for modal)

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});
```

---

> using templateUrl it throws an error

You should use local server rather than `file://` protocol (trying to guess your errors) or you can use **inline templates**, again from the example above:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
  HTML content here
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew I could add it in the original html file with the <script> tags, but I was trying to keep my code looking clean. Is that not poor practice? I'm very new to Angular and bootstrap so I'm not sure.

Comment: Of course. I usually keep my ```templates``` in ```templates``` folder. Glad you know alternative approach. How do you serve your files? Double click and directly in a browser or do you have some sort of development server? Also this would help - "using templateUrl it throws an error" - what type of error?

Comment: This is the error my dev tools gives me: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/test.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. I'm not sure what you mean by development server, but I'm closer to the double click and directly in browser. I'm using eclispe as my IDE and when I compile and run it automatically opens up chrome. Thank you

Comment: The magic keyword **development server** on Mac / Linux ```python -m SimpleHTTPServer``` on Windows: https://www.cesanta.com/mongoose The error message is relatively clear - if you just open file in a browser you cannot make requests to load external files... (when using ```templateUrl``` you try to load external file which is not allowed) Ensure the URL in the browser starts with ```localhost``` or some numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to use template url but will have to make your path relative:

ie.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
 animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
 templateUrl: "./Scripts/app/views/test.html",
 controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
 size: size,
 resolve: {
   car: function(){

    return $scope.car[index];
    }
  }  
});
```

Comment: So when I use templateUrl I get this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/test.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I personally find it easy to set the site up in IIS (or whichever webserver you are using) and that way relative file paths work.